# Need to do blank search.

Tags: search

When there is no value for parameter "s" , it redirects automatically to homepage.
Instead of this , I want to show all the information from my custom sql query.
how can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `s=%20` as your search string, but thats kinda hackish.

If what you are trying to achieve is to use your search.php template but with "controled" search results, consider using this:

```
<?php 

global $query_string; // fetch query string being used
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=20') // add your terms to it.

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom search form and use `<input type="hidden" name="s" value="whatever" />` in it, of course along with your usual search form (at the least an `<input type="text" name="search" />`).

Then, `$_GET['s']` will always be set. Remember to create a custom search page running your custom query (with `$_GET['search']` for the search terms), or you will find yourself always searching for the placeholder value you put in `$_GET['s']`.

You can see a live example of a solution similar to this at my site [Allt du behöver](http://www.alltdubehover.nu/) (unfortunately in Swedish but I think you can figure out how it works anyways).